# Raster calculator doesn't convert values properly

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator

I have some issues regarding QGIS Raster Calculator in my PC (I have installed two versions-2.18.26 and 3.14.15).

The problem is, I can't further edit rasterized layers which I converted from a vector format. I had set no data values to be 0, though, by using the information icon (i), these values are still appearing not to have data.

A friend of mine (QGIS specialist) told me to use the ("raster">=0)*"raster" function, which should have solved this problem. Nevertheless, this function doesnt change anything in the layer values when I'm executing it through my PC (in neither QGIS version), even though it perfectly works through my friend's PC.

Comment: What raster format do you use? Not all raster formats support NO DATA value. You can set NO DATA value in the raster layer properties window, on the Transparency tab.